# How to set the JMenubar in Titlebar?

Tags: java, swing, menubar, titlebar

I see many IDE or apps which have the menubar in the Titlebar itself between the icon and the title name. I just want to replicate it in Java using swing. I searched in Google but results were just how to add JMenuBar. How to place the JMenuBar in the Titlebar itself?

VSCode image

[image]

As you can see in the image the menubar is in the Titlebar itself along with icon, title and the window options.

Comment: Create an undecorated JFrame and create your own JPanel that looks and functions like a title bar.  Good luck recreating the JMenuBar.

Comment: @Abra, you might have seen it while using Intellij or VSCODE

Comment: The title bar is part of the OS window and java does NOT have access to it. You need to manually create your own titlebar which can then contain any components you want.

Comment: @Ruthvik An image doesn't help. you seemed to have ignored the other comments which have already suggested what you need to do the solve the problem.

Comment: @camickr, Sorry for ignoring, I just noticed now. Could you suggest ways or tell by links how can I do what you have suggested above..

Comment: I don't know of any links. Gilbert gave you a suggestion in the second comment hours ago. You need to create a panel that contains that replicates all the existing functionality of of the titlebar and also contains a menu bar. This is rather complex and most people don't do it since you will not have a common LAF across all platforms.

Comment: It's really complex I guess. I better go with the default ones

Comment: If it possible to use a title bar supplied by the look-and-feel, and place your JMenuBar on top of it, but the window title text would still be on the left side.  Getting the title bar’s text to move is probably too difficult to be worth the trouble.